# How to provide printer instructions in FHIR for specimen labels

Tags: hl7-fhir

We are implementing an API according to the FHIR standard.
Our clinic customers can have orders that include [Specimen](https://build.fhir.org/specimen.html), and we also want to provide the code for printing labels for these specimens (including barcodes, customer names and so on) on printers that support the [Zebra Programming language](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/ZPL-Command-Information-and-DetailsV2?language=en_US).

We have decided to do this in FHIR by using the [Device Resource](https://build.fhir.org/device.html) and storing the printer code in the [carrierAIDC](https://build.fhir.org/device-definitions.html#Device.udiCarrier.carrierAIDC) field as a base64 encoded string.

However, I am not certain that this is the optimal solution. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at using an extension instead? https://hl7.org/fhir/extensibility.html

Comment: Just a single small opinion, but I kinda like where you found it a home.   ....  The "type" might be the tricky part.  1..1 Cardinality.  and https://build.fhir.org/device-definitions.html#Device.property.type   not sure what you would use there.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would depend a bit on what the code for printing labels entails, and what attributes you are considering using to reference the various resources.  Are you intending to represent the label attached to the container that identifies the specimen in the container, the patient, etc.?  If so, Device.udiCarrier.carrierAIDC would not be the correct one to consider as that identifies the container, not the specimen in the container.  The Specimen would seem to be more appropriate as that is what the label primarily would represent (various Specimen attributes).  At this time you would need an extension to do that as there is no alternative attribute to handle the barcode/label code representation.

If the label does intent to primarily represent the container and the specimen, patient and other non-container data is ancillary to that, the Device.udiCarrier would be the closest as it is meant to identify the device specifically and has an attribute to represent the label content.  It likely would not yet be a full proper UDI, but creating a mostly parallel extension for doing the same seems to not be reasonable.  In this case I would suggest to request HL7 to consider clarifying the variety of label information that can be associated with a device, that aims to identify the device (not something else), and not limit it to UDI as defined today only.  If there is a concern that this may not be accepted, then go for an extension  for now.